# Node + socket.io chat server.. Could I miss some messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have done a couple of projects using Node JS & socket.io..

In my last project, which was building a chat-room like functionality, I did following things.

1. I rendered a blank box, where chat messages were to be shown.
2. Then I connect to the socket.io server.
3. When request for the connection goes to the server, I also push all the old chat messages of that chat-room to the browser.
4. In the middle of chat session, if any user gets disconnected coincidently(network failure), then upon reconnection all the old chat messages will be fetched & overwritten on the previous messages.

Now, I want to, is there a possibility that I can miss displaying some of the chat messages. I have not seen this happen so far.

What I was thinking is that what would happen if a message gets delivered by someone just at the of creating a connection. Is there a possibility that the new connection created won't get the message?

Pardon me if this sounds like a basic question, I am unable to think through with this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I was thinking is that what would happen if a message gets delivered by someone just at the of creating a connection. Is there a possibility that the new connection created won't get the message?

Ultimately, I don't think so. Node is a single-threaded server. Those two events will be executed in one, straightforward order. At least at the function level, your application code will never be run in an interleaved fashion, where it's handling both a new connection and a new message at the same time.

Your various callbacks may of course interleave with each other, so you'll have to reason about that. But once you're inside of a function, it will run to completion without any of your data being modified by any other parts of your code.

Comment: Thanks.. that is exactly what I thought.. Still I am interested in seeing what others have to say! :)

Answer (score 3):

A message being sent entirely on the server side, but not having been delivered to the client could happen if the connection is lost while the message is in flight. This should be a very low-frequency event, but it is possible.

To exclude the problem, why not introduce something like incremented message IDs?

On a reconnect, the client sends the ID of the last chat message it previously received, and the server sends any subsequent messages.

Comment: yes.. i can do that too.. right now, on connect/reconnect i am sending all the messages.. that can be avoided... Is there a chance of a message getting skipped in such a scenario?

Comment: Don't see how anything can get lost there. The last message ID is the client received stat and not connected to what the server has logged as sent.

Comment: My point is that what happens in case a message arrives in at the same time when a reconnect is taking place.. I hope some message won't be lost in that case either.. See Jason Reid's answer.. :)

Comment: This message hasn't been sent yet to the client, so it should be sent to it. This is something that you need to take into consideration, but then you have all the necessary information and control on the server side to do so.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.. Means I am going the right way.. :D :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that we can guess you can, you create an array[messages] with the last 10 or 20 posts, and when you connect it again to send. If the connection reset normal is to reload the page, and if you can not delete the default and include the last 20 posts, or you want to save!

Comment: I don't get you.. can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

**Server.js**

```
var nicknames = []
var old_messages = []

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){


socket.on('nickname',function(data, callback){

    if (nicknames.indexOf(data) != -1){
        callback(false);
    }else{
        callback(true);
        nicknames.push(data);
        socket.nickname = data;
        io.sockets.emit('nicknames', nicknames);

         //------------ send the old messages-------------
                    io.sockets.emit('old_messages', old_messages);


    }
});

socket.on('user message',function (data){

       // ------------ Update de old_message list --------------
            old_messages.push(socket.nickname + " - " +data);
            if (old_messages.length > 10)
            {var aux = old_messages.pop()}


    io.sockets.emit('user message', {
        nick: socket.nickname,
        message: data
    });
});

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    if (!socket.nickname) return;
    if (nicknames.indexOf(socket.nickname) > -1){
    nicknames.splice(nicknames.indexOf(socket.nickname),1);
    }
    io.sockets.emit('nicknames', nicknames);
});
});
```

**Client.js**

```
 var socket = io.connect();
 jQuery(function ($) {
var sendMessage= $('#send-message');
var nickName = $('#nickname');
var setNicknameForm = $('#set-nickname');
var firstTime = true;

setNicknameForm.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('nickname',nickName.val(),function(data){
        if (
            setNicknameForm.hide();
            sendMessage.show();
        } else {
            setNicknameForm.prepend('<p> Ya esta cogido </p>');
        }
    // Uptade messages
    socket.on ('old_messages', function(data){
        if (firstTime){
            for (var i=1; i<data.length(); i++){
                $('#messages').append($('<p>').text(data[i]));
            };
                            firsTime = false;
        };

    });

    socket.on('nicknames',function(data){
        $('#nicknames').empty().append($('<ul>'));
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            $('#nicknames ul').append('<li>' + data[i]);
        }
    });

    });
});

sendMessage.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('user message',$('#message').val());
    $('#message').val('');

});

socket.on('user message',function(data){
    $('#messages').append($('<p>').text(data.nick+" - "+data.message));
});
```